# unable to display table data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need to display a task table in a view, the column value "task_name" in show.blade.file @ tasks folder this is `TaskController`

```
 public function store(Request $request)//, $id, Task $task)
        {
            $task = new Task;
            $task->task_name= $request->input('name');
            $task->body = $request->input('body');
            $task->assign = $request->input('status');
            $task->priority = $request->input('status');
            $task->duedate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));// $request->input('date');
          //  $task->project_id = $id;
            $task->save();
        }

        public function show($id)
        {
            $task = Task::find($id);
            return view('tasks.show')->withTasks($task);
        }
 public function getTasks($id)
    {
        $tasks =  Task::find($id)->get();
        return $tasks;
    }
```

**show.blade.php**

```
 @if(isset($tasks))
     @foreach($tasks as $ta)
    <h1>{{ $ta->task_name }}</h1>
    @endforeach
    @endif
```

routes.php

```
Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');
```

No, any error but not display task_name in the task table

Comment: are you print the data `$task = Task::find($id);` is it contain value ?

Comment: did you mean  public function getTasks($id)
    {
        $tasks =  Task::find($id)->get();
        return $tasks;
    }

Comment: Yes, dd($task) and post the output please

Comment: i am asking that the value is present in ` $tasks ` ?

Comment: edit My TaskController please see

Comment: in the show() do you have data there ?

Comment: No. grab the data using $tasks = Task::find($id);

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
public function show($id)
 {
 $task = Task::find($id)->get();;           
 return view('tasks.show',['tasks' => $task]);
}
```

Comment: same thing no change

Comment: then just run this and show me the output `$task = Task::find($id);  dd($task )        
 return view('tasks.show',['tasks' => $task]);`

Comment: same thing here

Comment: then you are not getting the data

Comment: try this again .